# Nested JSON array displaying as [Object Object] in TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have two sets of JSON, **Set 1** and **Set 2**. **Set 1** (`sizingData`) being mapped to textFields like this:

```
const fillTextField = () => {
    let result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(sizingHistory);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        result.push(sizingHistory[key]);
    });
    return( 
        {result?.map((data) => {
            return ( <TextField variant="outlined" value={data} /> );
        })}
    )
}
```

I want to map **Set 2** (`sizingHistory`) similarly, but I am getting `[Object Object]` in the textField rather than the `SizingId` & `SizingComments`.  This is my attempt at mapping `sizinhHistory`:

```
const [sizingHistory, setSizingHistory] = useState("");
const fillHistoryTextField = () => {
    let result = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(sizingHistory["sizinghistory"]);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        result.push(sizingHistory["sizinghistory"][key]);
    });
    return (
        {result?.map((data) => {
            return ( <TextField variant="outlined" value={data} /> );
        })}
    )
}
```

Set 1

```
{
    "SizingId": 20448,
    "SizingComments": "This is a comment",
}
```

Set 2

```
{
    "sizinghistory" : [
        "SizingId" : 20448,
        "SizingComments": "Old Comment",
    ]
}
```

The fetch function for both `sizingData` & `sizingHistory` are called in their own `handleOpen` functions.  `UseEffect` cannot be used in this case as data is only displayed when a user selects a row in a table containing a `SizingId`.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Your elements are objects, so they get converted to string, and the default conversion to string on a plain object gives you the string `"[object Object]"`. Use the object's properties, rather than using the objects directly.

Comment: Might seem obvious, but this implies you've not converted the object to a string. Have you tried [`JSON.stringify(sizingHistory)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

Comment: I have updated the question to show my attempt at displaying ``sizingHistory``.  Using JSON.stringify(sizingHistory)`` results in over a hundred TextFields being rendered each with 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [Object object] as JS is converting an object to string on `Set2`, this happens because data.seizingHistory is an array and you have to iterate through it then through the keys of the object inside to get all the data on the text inputs.

This should get you what you need

```
const [sizingHistory, setSizingHistory] = useState("");
const fillHistoryTextField = () => {
    let result = [];

    (sizingHistory["sizinghistory"]).forEach(element => {
      const keys = Object.keys(element);
      keys.forEach(function (key) {
          result.push(element[key]);
      });
    });

    return (
        {result?.map((data) => {
            return ( <TextField variant="outlined" value={data} /> );
        })}
    )
}
```